# Errors while Exporting XLS using PHP over secure connections

Tags: php, mysql, https, xls

I am working on a PHP MYSQL system which needs to generate XLS files, the system works fine on a normal http connection but while trying to export the XLS file using PHP over a https connection the file isnt generated.

Are there specific techniques that should be used while generating XLS files over a secure connection?

Thanks

Comment: Please give a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) of the code that's causing this problem.

Comment: Is this using IE? If so, then you need to set the correct headers for it to work over SSL - see the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064535/excel-export-problem-in-ie for more details